# How to handle optional/missing attributes of related Core Data objects in NDPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I've recently ran into an issue with core data that I'm unable to solve.

I have the following object and relationships `Recommendation <---> Item`

```
extension Recommendation {
  @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Recommendation> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Recommendation>(entityName: "Recommendation")
  }

  @NSManaged public var age: Int?
  @NSManaged public var tags: Array<String>?
  @NSManaged public var object: Item?
}

extension Item {
  @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Item> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Recommendation>(entityName: "Item")
  }

  @NSManaged public var id: String?
  @NSManaged public var name: String?
  @NSManaged public var recommendation: Recommendation?
}
```

I want to fetch all `Item`s based on attributes in their related `Recommendation`.
Some of these attributes could be missing.

How would I create a NSPredicate to fetch objects where the `Recommendation.age` or `Recommendation.tags` could be non-existent (applicable to all ages/tags) or should be compared against a provided value?

Should I always provide a Default Value?

Comment: A predicate evaluates `nil` to `false` (doesn't match).

Comment: Thanks for that info. Does that also apply to relationships? 
Could I do something like `NSPredicate(format: "%K == false", #keyPath(Item.recommendation))`?